# XPath for nodes which only have certain attributes?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

For example, I only want the `script` nodes which only have `type` attribute, i.e. the first one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//script[@type and not(@*[name() != "type"])]
```

will select all `script` elements that have a `@type` attribute and no other attributes.

---

This XPath,

```
//script[not(@*[name() != "type"])]
```

will select all `script` elements that have no attributes not named `type`.  It's like the first XPath except doesn't require that `@type` be present – it'll also select `<script/>`.